# Parse windows С++ project files using libclang (with VC code base)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I needed to parse AST of my project that written with VS C++. So I compiled llvm/clang and used it's API to Parse AST.

But got next error:

```
G:/Hades/Hades/source/Main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'memory' file not found
#include <memory>
         ^~~~~~~~
```

Then I specified headerSearch for preprocessor and added path: `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include"` to HeaderSearchOptions (by using `HeaderSearchOptions::AddPath`) to detect missing includes.

But it caused a lot of errors during parsing VC headers, here is part of log:

```
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\memory:9:
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\yvals_core.h:297:
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\vcruntime.h:58:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\vadefs.h:61:33: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
        typedef unsigned __int64  uintptr_t;
                                ^
                                ;
In file included from G:/Hades/Hades/source/Main.cpp:2:
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\memory:9:
In file included from C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\yvals_core.h:297:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\vcruntime.h:96:1: warning: declaration specifier missing, defaulting to 'int'
_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER
^
int
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\vcruntime.h:69:9: note: expanded from macro '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER'
        __pragma(pack(push, _CRT_PACKING)) \
        ^
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\vcruntime.h:96:1: error: use of undeclared identifier 'push'
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\vcruntime.h:69:23: note: expanded from macro '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER'
        __pragma(pack(push, _CRT_PACKING)) \
                      ^
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\vcruntime.h:96:1: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/include\vcruntime.h:70:9: note: expanded from macro '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER'
        extern "C" {
```

How can I solve this? Probably I should specify some options somewhere to let get clang know about how specific it must be parsed these sources if it's MS sources?

Or must I use another code base of standard includes? And probably I must to somehow skip includes like `Windows.h` due to it's only Windows header?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a weird workaround as memory.h should be a part of the standard libraries.

try using
https://developer.mindsphere.io/resources/mindconnect-lib/doxygen/html/memory_8h.html

`#include "mcl/mcl_common.h"`

might work and give all the necessary things